# Prove cyclic inequality

Tags: inequality

Please help me to prove this.

Assume$\forall n,a_n>0$, then
$${a_1a_2\over a_3}+{a_2a_3\over a_4}+\dots+{a_{n-1}a_n\over a_1}+{a_na_1\over a_2}\geq a_1+\dots+a_n.$$

I can prove for $n=3$, but it seems impossible to extend it to the general case. Please help to prove. Thanks.

For $n=3$, it is easy to show
$${ab\over c}+{bc\over a}+{ca\over{{{{b}}}}}\geq a+b+c\iff{1\over c^2}+{1\over a^2}+{1\over {{{{b}}}}^2}\geq{1\over{   {{cb}}}}+{1\over{ac}}+{1\over{a {{b}}}}$$
which holds following$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca.$$
But it seems hard to extend it.

Comment: So for all $n$ and $a_1,\dots,a_n$? The above is really awkward notation.

Comment: Sorry for the poor notation. I have expanded it.

Comment: OK. It's Done. Thanks.

Comment: @Macavity oops! you are right! thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Set $a_i = e^{x_i}$ so that we need to show:
$$\sum_{cyc} e^{x_1+x_2-x_3} \ge \sum_{cyc} e^{x_1}$$
and use Karamata's inequality.

---

To show the majorization, apart from showing the double stochastic matrix, here is a more elementary though cumbersome way: Let $x_{i_1}+x_{i_1+1}-x_{i_1+2} \ge x_{i_2}+x_{i_2+1}-x_{i_2+2} \ge \dots \ge x_{i_n}+x_{i_n+1}-x_{i_n+2}$ and $x_{j_1} \ge x_{j_2} \ge \dots \ge x_{j_n}$ for some indices $i_k, j_k \in \{1, 2, ... n\}$.

Then, obviously $  x_{i_1}+x_{i_1+1}-x_{i_1+2} \ge x_{j_1}+x_{j_1+1}-x_{j_1+2} \ge x_{j_1}$.

Similarly, $(x_{i_1}+x_{i_1+1}-x_{i_1+2})+(x_{i_2}+x_{i_2+1}-x_{i_2+2}) \ge (x_{j_1}+x_{j_1+1}-x_{j_1+2})+(x_{j_2}+x_{j_2+1}-x_{j_2+2}) \ge x_{j_1}+x_{j_2}$ and so on.

Comment: I don't see why $\{x_1+x_2-x_3\}$majorises$\{x_1\}$ or can you shed some more light?

Comment: @user214607 There is a "doubly stochastic" matrix at play here. Look up the "Equivalent conditions" section of the Wikiepdia page on majorization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization

Comment: OK. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong!

Try $n=4$ and $$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,20,2,6)$$